# How to add SUM aggregate function into Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query:

```
var resultb = unitOfWork.deviceInstanceRepository.Get()
            .Select(s => new
            {
                DeviceId = s.DeviceId,
                Name = s.Device.Name,
                Manufacturer = s.Device.Manufacturer1.Name,
                Quantity = s.Quantity
            })
            .GroupBy(w => new
            {
                w.DeviceId,
                w.Name,
                w.Manufacturer,
                w.Quantity
            }).ToList();
```

I want to change this line:
`Quantity= s.Quantity`

into

`Quantity=Sum(s=>s.Quantity)`

I found this [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb534734%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
but still have some problems with implementing this. There is no Sum method in Intellisense.

Ok when I change places of `Select` and `GroupBy` :

```
var resultb = unitOfWork.deviceInstanceRepository.Get()
            .GroupBy(w => new
            {
                w.DeviceId,
                w.Device.Name,
                w.Device.Manufacturer,
                w.Quantity
            })
            .Select(s => new
            {
                DeviceId = s.DeviceId,
                Name = s.Device.Name,
                Manufacturer = s.Device.Manufacturer1.Name,
                Quantity = s.Sum(s=>s.Quantity)
            })
```

I can use `Sum` but then lines like : `s.DeviceId` throws error that `Anonymous type does not contain definition of deviceId`.
Same error for `s.Device.Name` and `s>device.Manufacuter1.Name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must do the grouping without the `Quantity` property, because that is the property you want to aggregate in the grouping:

```
unitOfWork.deviceInstanceRepository.Get()
          .GroupBy(w => new
          {
              DeviceId = w.DeviceId,
              Device = w.Device.Name,
              Manufacturer = w.Device.Manufacturer,
          })
          .Select(s => new
          {
              DeviceId = s.Key.DeviceId,
              Name = s.Key.Device,
              Manufacturer = s.Key.Manufacturer.Name,
              Quantity = s.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
          })
```

Comment: Thanks. But what this is still problems with `Device` Key has no such thing as `Device`

Comment: It's always good practice to explicitly name properties in an anonymous type to prevent such errors, see the edit.